# updating existing Mongo collection object in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I saw the other answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016149/meteor-mongo-finding-and-updating-certain-elements-in-a-collection), however I think mine is a little more specific.

I have `Meteor.user()` as `Object {_id: "iymu2h9uysCiKFHvc", emails: Array[2], profile: Object, services: Object}`

and I'm running a function to set the profile first name and last name here:

```
thisId = Meteor.userId();

Meteor.users.update({ _id: thisId }, { $set: {
  profile: {
    first_name: $('#firstName').val(),
    last_name: $('#lastName').val()
  }
}
});
```

I also, however, would like to, on a different event, add a a `notifications` object to the profile.
I tried :

```
 thisId = Meteor.userId();

  Meteor.users.update({ _id: thisId }, { $set: {
    profile: {
      notifications: {
        rcptDwnldFile: Session.get('recpt-dwnld-file'),
        rcptPaysInv: Session.get('recpt-pays-inv'),
        invSentDue: Session.get('inv-sent-due'),
        // the rest
      }
    }
  }
});
```

but that overrides my `first_name`, `last_name` entries. I also tried `$setOnInstert` but i get a `update failed: Access denied. Operator $setOnInsert not allowed in a restricted collection.` but I thought that `profile` was writable by the user by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this instead (more info [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) - see section **Set Fields in Embedded Documents**):

```
thisId = Meteor.userId();

Meteor.users.update({ _id: thisId }, { $set: {
    'profile.first_name': $('#firstName').val(),
    'profile.last_name': $('#lastName').val()  
}
});
```

and

```
thisId = Meteor.userId();

Meteor.users.update({ _id: thisId }, { $set: {
        'profile.notifications.rcptDwnldFile': Session.get('recpt-dwnld-file'),
        'profile.notifications.rcptPaysInv': Session.get('recpt-pays-inv'),
        'profile.notifications.invSentDue': Session.get('inv-sent-due'),
        // the rest          
  }
});
```